# Posso utilizar display: flex quando uso viewport?

Tags: css

Sou iniciante no desenvolvimento de sites responsivos e estou usando a tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

E além disso na construção de contêineres estou usando `display: flex` no css e usando medidas em `vw` e `vh` fazer essa  combinação é possível ou não é aconselhável?

Comment: Pode sim, a única coisa que o META view-port muda é a limitação da largura e a escala do ZOOM (ou desabilita o zoom-in e zoom-out).

Comment: Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento, vlw man